# What's the significance of having no members in an abstract class?

Tags: dart

`Exception` class looks like:

```
abstract class Exception {
  factory Exception([var message]) => _Exception(message);
}
```

`_Exception` class is the implementation of it. As you can see there are no fields or functions declared in this class other than a factory constructor, so what's the significance of having such classes?

Comment: So there can be a common base class to catch that is narrower than `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like a [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) which tells the *reader* that a subclass is intended to be used as an exception (thrown in a situation where the user is expected to catch and handle the exceptional situation, rather than an error).

Dart, the language, does not treat `Exception` specially. It's completely unnecessary from a technical point of view since all objects can be thrown. Making your class implement `Exception` signifies that it's *purpose* is to be thrown, even though it is not an `Error`, but you should see it as documentation, not something your program can meaningfully use.

Exceptions, unlike `Error`s, are intended to be caught and *handled*, just as much as a return value is. An exception should contain enough information to make the receiver able to do something meaningful.
Because of that, you should *never* throw a plain `Exception` in production code (so the constructor is really deprecated except during development, until you have created a proper exception class).

Similarly, you should never *catch* a plain `Exception` (no `on Exception catch (e) {...}`) because then you are not handling the actual problem. If you just want to catch *anything*, use `on Object`, because code can throw any class, and not all exception classes need to implement `Exception`.

Comment: Sir, what's the significance of having the constructor then? Isn't it redundant?

Comment: It's not redundant, more like superfluous. It's mainly there for historical reasons, because some people do throw `new Exception("Problem found")` even though they shouldn't, and we don't want to break their code unnecessarily.